# Create EventHanlder inside Object Javascript

Tags: jquery, object, event-handling

I was wondering if this was possible using jquery or standard javascript

```
function myObj (x,y)
{
 this.x=x;
 this.y=y;
 //above doesn't really matter much
 // real question below
 $(this).click(function(){
 //place some javascript fucnction in here to run when something happens
 });

}
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

How will your object catch an event? As for your handler, you can invoke it using `$(myObj).trigger('click')` from outside of your function

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question! But you can add cutom jQuery events to your code like this:

```
$('body').trigger('myevent');
```

Then, from somewhere else in your code, you can listen to this event, and execute some code when it is fired:

```
$('body').bind('myevent', function(){
     // code here
});
```